# How to conclude $\Re $ is zero?

Tags: hilbert-spaces

I'm in a Hilbert space $H$ and for $z,v, h \in H$ and $t \in \mathbb C$ I have

$$ \|z\|^2 \leq \|h−(tv+y)\|^2 = \|z−tv\|^2 =\|z\|^2 −2\Re(t⟨v,z⟩)+|t|^2\|v\|^2$$

According to my notes it follows from this that $\Re(t⟨v,z⟩) = 0$ for all $t$. How does that follow? I can't seem to show it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We get that for all $t\in\Bbb C$,
$$2\Re(t\langle v,z\rangle)\leq |t|^2\lVert v\rVert^2.$$
For an integer $n$, replacing $t$ by $\frac tn$, we get:
$$\frac 2n\Re(t\langle v,z\rangle)\leq \frac 1{n^2}|t|^2\lVert v\rVert^2,$$
hence 
$$2\Re(t\langle v,z\rangle)\leq \frac 1n|t|^2\lVert v\rVert^2.$$
Letting $n\to +\infty$, we show the result.

Comment: This is awesome! That's a cool trick. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Matt Yes, you are right. I will edit it.

Comment: Ok. : ) (I removed my now obsolete comment.)

Comment: Couldn't you also take $t$ real, cancel a factor of $t$, and take the limit as $t$ tends to zero?